# Url is not a valid virtual path

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a hyperlink that passes variables with it. This is generating using a combination of strings and server properties. However it seems to work with some variables but not others.

If I pass the groupId and issuedMemberId then it's fine.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="groupUrlLink" NavigateUrl=<%# string.Concat("~/UpdateMember.aspx?groupId=", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "GroupID").ToString(),"&issuedMemberId=", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IssuedMemberId").ToString()%> >
```

However if I instead use a different variable, Effective date,

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="groupUrlLink" NavigateUrl=<%# string.Concat("~/UpdateMember.aspx?groupId=", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "GroupID").ToString(),"&effectiveDate=",DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EffectiveDate").ToString())%> >
```

I get an error:

> '~/UpdateMember.aspx?groupId=0032409901&effectiveDate=3/31/2008
>   12:00:00 AM' is not a valid virtual path.

As can be seen in the error it is correctly using the value for the Effective date. This is the only thing to have changed though from the first example so I'm not sure why it isn't working now.

Comment: Is it because of the slashes in the date?
I would imagine that the Hyperlink control would automatically encode any special characters in its URL, but you can check it by looking at the rendered HTML source in the browser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably the forward slashes (in the parameter section of the URL) or the space. It is not valid characters for an URL.

Use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` to encode the URL. Or as the comment below specifies.

Comment: To add to your answer, the OP should probably use a `WebUtility.HttpEncode(...)` call around the string passed to the `NavigateUrl` property of the `Hyperlink`. See my answer for specifics.

Comment: Thanks, I tried NavigateUrl=<%# WebUtility.HttpEncode(string.Concat.....    but it doesn't recognise WebUtility. To try and solve this I placed <%@ Import Namespace="System.Net" %> at the top of the page but it just goes grey and says it's not beign used while WebUtility is still unrecognised

Comment: Yeah, that's because I got the method name wrong. `WebUtility.UrlEncode` it should've been. But, since it's an ASP.net app, it really doesn't matter whether you use `WebUtility` or `HttpUtility`, they're the same exact method. `WebUtility` was introduced into the `System.Net` namespace so that 1) you don't necessarily need to take a dependence on `System.Web` and 2) I believe for things like using the `HttpWebClient`. Thanks for the consideration, though.

Comment: you saved my day. +1000 ;)

Answer (score 2):

To add to the answer above, the OP should probably use a `WebUtility.HttpEncode(...)` call around 
the string passed to the `NavigateUrl` property of the `Hyperlink`:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="groupUrlLink" NavigateUrl=<%# WebUtility.UrlEncode(string.Concat("~/UpdateMember.aspx?groupId=", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "GroupID").ToString(),"&effectiveDate=",DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EffectiveDate").ToString())) %> >
```

**UPDATE:** In general, you should always make sure you encode data sent via URL to ensure that malicious input doesn't lead to some sort of script injection, cross-site scripting attack, or other nefarious intents.

Answer (score 2):

Use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` or `Ticks` when passing `DateTime`. I would suggest you to pass `Ticks` when passing `DateTime` in query string. `Ticks` is of long data type which can be converted to `DateTime`.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="groupUrlLink" NavigateUrl=<%# string.Concat("~/UpdateMember.aspx?groupId=", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "GroupID").ToString(),"&effectiveDate=",DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EffectiveDate").Ticks.ToString())%> >
```

Comment: I tried this but I i get a compile error saying that Ticks is not recognised

Answer (score 1):

you can send datetime as `Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EffectiveDate")).ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")`

then you can again convert query string value back to datetime using `DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMddHHmmss")`

Comment: I tried this but I get a redline under the argument to the ToString function and when I try to compile it I get an error saying that no method for ToString takes 1 argument. I think maybe it isn't recognising it as a Datetime Object

Comment: if it is not DateTime you can convert to DateTime